# Java regex to replace whitespaces in css class string with dots

Tags: java, html, css, regex

Given a `class` attribute of an HTML element, I want to generate a String suitable for css selector.

For instance, the element's `class` attribute value:

```
'  foo bar  baz '
```

OR

```
'foo bar  baz '
```

Should both become a css selector:

```
'.foo.bar.baz'
```

Right now, I'm using:

```
String classCssSelector = "." + classProp.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", ".");
```

But I want to get rid of the leading hardcoded `"." +` and the `trim()` and make it all one `replaceAll` call.

**EDIT**:

I used the regex provided in @anubhava's answer, but then wanted it to also match an already 'dotted' class like this:

```
'  foo bar  baz '
```

The following regex works for both cases:

```
^(?!\.)| +(?= *\S)
```

Comment: @anubhava: What if there is no leading space in the original string?

Comment: It adds redundant dots... Won't work in this case 'foo bar  baz '.

Comment: it will even add the dot at the end as per OP's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in `replaceAll`:

```
^ *| +(?= *\S)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH3jR7/2)

**Code:**

```
String classCssSelector = classProp.replaceAll("^ *| +(?= *\\S)", ".");
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         - Match beginning
^ *       - Match 0 or more spaces at start
|         - Alternation in regex
| +       - Match 1 more spaces after `|`
(?= *\\S) - Lookahead to make sure there is at least one non-space character after matching
            space in previous match
```

Comment: but it leaves the trailing spaces as it is. @Elist did you want to remove the trailing spaces?

Comment: @AvinashRaj is right. I do want to remove them, but I guess it can't be done with one `replaceAll` call.

Comment: @Elist: That's right, you can call trim after this `replaceAll` call since we can either replace by dot OR by `""` in 2nd argument of `replaceAll`.